# How to find optimal parameters in Gaussian basis set?

Tags: matrices, optimization, exponential-function, normal-distribution, change-of-basis

I decide to ask my question (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/755354/how-to-find-optimal-parameters-in-gaussian-basis-set) in MATHEMATICS part of StackExchange too, because I think the question relate to some math approach.

I try to replicate some results of this article - https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/pssb.2220930140

The article here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q74hAn0UAdNd8DtPkoCsdYPkr61-xhr2/view?usp=sharing

I would like to get energies of ground state for Hydrogen atom in magnetic field. But I can't understand, how to find $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ sets for Gaussian basis functions.

Brief description of the problem:

Hamiltonian of Hydrogen atom in magnetic field ($\vec{B}||z$) has the following form (formula (2) in the article): $$H=-\Delta-\frac{2}{r}+\gamma l_z+\frac{1}{4}(\gamma^2 \rho^2)$$ where $\quad r^2=\rho^2+z^2 \quad \gamma=\frac{\mu B}{R} \quad \mu=\frac{e \hbar}{2 m c} \quad R=\frac{mc^4}{2\epsilon_0^2\hbar^2}$

The authors use for the Hamiltonian matrix numerical diagonaliztion Gausian basis set (formula (4) in the article): $$\psi_i=\rho^{|m|}e^{im\phi}z^qe^{-\alpha_i r^2-\beta_i z^2}$$ where $m=0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3...$ is the quantum number describing the $z $ component of the angular momentum, $q = 0,1$

the $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are coefficients of geometric progressions (formulas (8a) and (8b) in the article): $\alpha_i=\alpha_{i-1} \left( \frac{\alpha_N}{\alpha_1} \right)^{1/(N-1)}$, $\beta_i=\beta_{i-1} \left( \frac{\beta_M}{\beta_1} \right)^{1/(M-1)}$ . This is accomplished by specifying four quantities - the largest and smallest exponents from the $\alpha$ and $\beta$ sets: $\alpha_1$,  $\alpha_N$, $ \beta_1$, $ \beta_M$

Let's consider the lowest energy ($m=0, q=0$), then the basis functions will take the form: $$\psi_i=e^{-\alpha_i r^2-\beta_i z^2}$$

But I really can't understand how need to find these parameters: $\alpha_1$,  $\alpha_N$, $ \beta_1$, $ \beta_M$ ?

The authors write the following: "For given quantum numbers $m$ and $q$, the parameters $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_N$, $\beta_1$, and $\beta_M$ were varied in a four dimensional optimization search which minimized the sum of the eigen-values of interest"

Could you please explain to me what the authors mean? 
How to find the $\alpha_1$,  $\alpha_N$, $ \beta_1$, $ \beta_M$ parameters?

Comment: You're missing a $\varphi$ in the exponent of $\mathrm e^{\mathrm im\varphi}$ in the basis functions.

Comment: This is a paper from 1979. A **huge** amount of work has been done in this field since then. Basis sets have evolved with the capabilities of computers. It seems highly unlikely that this particular basis set that these particular authors used at that particular time will be particularly useful in any modern calculation. Could you say something about why you're trying to reproduce their results?

Comment: @joriki, thanks! I have corrected this typo

Comment: @joriki, I agree that this work is old and I came out to this work from references from more modern works. This work has a few advantages, it has been written simplest (except of finding of parameters (my question)) and energy values for medium magnetic fields have a good agreement with values from more modern works, which describes improved methods of calculations. I have tried to understand two another articles (more modern), but they are more complicated and their approaches have advantage only for strong fields.